# How to create media sink in win 8 metro

Tags: windows, window, microsoft-metro

I have a problem: I want to capture video and audio from webcam and micro to stream, and display it in other machine 
I tried Realtime-communication sample, they use custom media sink, but it so complex, so can somebody show me a simple sample about it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the video link in cloud and access the data using the program from other pc.